# Polymer - Modify element's attribute in CSS

Tags: css, mouseevent, polymer, polymer-1.0

Say I have a `paper-material` element and I want to increase the `elevation` value on `mouseover`. However I don't want this to happen on smaller screens so a media query like:

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  paper-material:hover {
    elevation: 2; /* This doesn't work */
  }
}
```

should do the trick - except it doesn't. The `paper-material` itself is doing nothing special:

```
<paper-material elevation="1">
  <p>I wish I could go up!</p>
</paper-material>
```

Now I can do this (sort-of) using the `on-mouseover` value. In this case I can have two event handlers to do the `moverover` and `mouseout`.

```
<paper-material elevation="1" on-mouseover="elevateCard" on-mouseout="demoteCard">
  <p>I wish I could go up!</p>
</paper-material>

...

elevateCard: function(event) {
      event.srcElement.setAttribute('elevation', 2);
}
demoteCard: function(event) {
      event.srcElement.setAttribute('elevation', 1);
}
```

I'm not too happy with this approach as it requires the elevation levels to be in a `script` tag (I guess this can be abstracted away but that's another issue) and more importantly, it seems like a lot of extra code that the CSS `:hover` attribute is already capable of doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that with the native api for the element you're using. You could work around it by yourself applying the css rules the element itself uses, such as:

```
  @media (min-width: 1100px) {
    paper-material:hover {
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-4dp);
    }
  }
```

(If you have imported the element you have already imported `/paper-styles/shadow.html` which is required)

However, I don't see anything immediately wrong with your solution. You could put the 'levels' as attributes on the element.

```
<paper-material data-next-elevation="2" elevation="1" on-mouseover="elevateCard" on-mouseout="demoteCard">
```

And then just use `elem.getAttribute('data-next-elevation')` and apply it whenever you need. That way you have keep the logic for the element in one place.

Comment: This would work but feels like a lot of extra code to handle something the browser already does `:hover`. Anyhow I'll probably have to use this method if I can't come up with an alternative.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer simply because it does the intended work (albeit more verbosely than I'd like) and there isn't any other viable answer here.